# Web2py Modules and Doctests

Tags: web2py, doctest, web2py-modules

I have a module applications/webapp/modules/a.py that contains a local_import to import applications/webapp/modules/b.py. I want to doctest a.py and b.py. The web2py shell with "-T" option partially works but complains with the exception pasted below after saying "Finding tests in a.py: **class**".

I understand that this is because the "-T" option is meant only for testing controllers. But due to local_import within a.py there is no easy way to doctest a.py outside of the web2py environment. So how should I go about refactoring the modules so that I can doctest them?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "web2py.py", line 19, in 
>       gluon.widget.start(cron=True)   File
>   "/home/.../web2py/gluon/widget.py",
>   line 796, in start
>       test(options.test, verbose=options.verbose)   File
>   "/home/.../web2py/gluon/shell.py",
>   line 326, in test
>       doctest_object(name, obj)   File "/home/.../web2py/gluon/shell.py",
>   line 322, in doctest_object
>       doctest_object(attr_name, o)   File
>   "/home/.../web2py/gluon/shell.py",
>   line 321, in doctest_object
>       o = eval('%s.%s' % (name, attr_name), globs)   File "",
>   line 1, in  NameError: name
>   '**class**' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://markmail.org/thread/vaxwkbisfnz5aqku), I made an attempt as follows. It works fine as of now but not sure if this is the best approach. In private/ folder, create a file tests.py with:

```
from gluon.shell import env
globals().update(env('webapp', import_models=True))

a = local_import('a')

import doctest
doctest.testmod(a, verbose=True)
```

Moreover, in a.py I used 'import b' instead of 'local_import(b)' as per [this](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/browse_thread/thread/a623c634af3e3778).

Run the tests using:

```
python web2py.py -S webapp --run applications/webapp/private/tests.py
```

Comment: Also, as of the recently released version 1.96.x, you no longer need to use local_import at all -- you can just use regular import statements, even from models and controllers.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for the awesomely useful information. More here: http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/browse_thread/thread/ff3863c566b8b405/b96cd8f3b44e53d6